# Column 'CIHeader.InvoiceDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    CI.InvoiceNo,
    CI.InvoiceDate,
    SUM(CI.TaxAmount + CI.InvoiceAmount) AS Amount,
    cd.CourierId,
    cd.DoketNo,
    cd.CourierCompanyName,
    cd.NoOfBoxes,
    cd.Weigth,
    cd.CourierRefNo
FROM CourierDetail AS cd
INNER JOIN CIHeader AS CI
    ON CI.CourierId = cd.CourierId
WHERE
    (ISNULL('I/B0023/13/071199', '') = ''
    OR CI.InvoiceNo LIKE '%I/B0023/13/071199%')
```

Error is:

> Column 'CIHeader.InvoiceDate' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want the **sum of the columns**

```
CI.TaxAmount + CI.InvoiceAmount
```

remuve SUM (be sure that the colums are numeric),

if you need to add the sum on rows columns, you have to include the columns in select statement in GROUP BY

```
   SELECT
CI.InvoiceNo,
CI.InvoiceDate,
SUM(CI.TaxAmount + CI.InvoiceAmount) AS Amount,
cd.CourierId,
cd.DoketNo,
cd.CourierCompanyName,
cd.NoOfBoxes,
cd.Weigth,
cd.CourierRefNo
FROM CourierDetail AS cd
INNER JOIN CIHeader AS CI
ON CI.CourierId = cd.CourierId
WHERE
    (ISNULL('I/B0023/13/071199', '') = ''
OR CI.InvoiceNo LIKE '%I/B0023/13/071199%')
GROUP BY
    CI.InvoiceNo,
    CI.InvoiceDate,
    cd.CourierId,
    cd.DoketNo,
    cd.CourierCompanyName,
    cd.NoOfBoxes,
    cd.Weigth,
    cd.CourierRefNo
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use aggregate function SUM, COUNT, MAX, MIN, AVG with other columns in select statement then you will have to include them (the column not in aggregate function) in GROUP BY clause.

```
    SELECT
        CI.InvoiceNo,
        CI.InvoiceDate,
        SUM(CI.TaxAmount + CI.InvoiceAmount) AS Amount,
        cd.CourierId,
        cd.DoketNo,
        cd.CourierCompanyName,
        cd.NoOfBoxes,
        cd.Weigth,
        cd.CourierRefNo
    FROM CourierDetail AS cd
    INNER JOIN CIHeader AS CI
        ON CI.CourierId = cd.CourierId
    WHERE
        (ISNULL('I/B0023/13/071199', '') = ''
        OR CI.InvoiceNo LIKE '%I/B0023/13/071199%')
    GROUP BY
        CI.InvoiceNo,
        CI.InvoiceDate,
        cd.CourierId,
        cd.DoketNo,
        cd.CourierCompanyName,
        cd.NoOfBoxes,
        cd.Weigth,
        cd.CourierRefNo
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CI.InvoiceNo" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CI.InvoiceDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CI.TaxAmount" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CI.InvoiceAmount" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

If  CI.InvoiceNo is primary key and uniq

```
SELECT
CI.InvoiceNo,
CI.InvoiceDate,
(SELECT SUM(innerCI.TaxAmount + innerCI.InvoiceAmount) 
FROM CIHeader AS innerCI WHERE innerCI.InvoiceNo = CI.InvoiceNo ) AS Amount,
cd.CourierId,
cd.DoketNo,
cd.CourierCompanyName,
cd.NoOfBoxes,
cd.Weigth,
cd.CourierRefNo
FROM CourierDetail AS cd
INNER JOIN CIHeader AS CI
ON CI.CourierId = cd.CourierId
WHERE
(ISNULL('I/B0023/13/071199', '') = ''
OR CI.InvoiceNo LIKE '%I/B0023/13/071199%')
```